# I feel like my Gmail is being used by different people previously

Tags: google-chrome, email, security, gmail

I feel like my email was used by anonymous people, can I get the list of devices that connected my Gmail account. Not just recent, every device which used my mail account with their ip address , device type and date time. I am really worried. Anyone please help.

Regards
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of currently logged in devices, but I don't think they provide an IP address just a GEO location and a device type. Here is a [link](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity). Also, if you are concerned with others using your account, change your password (use a strong, preferably random password) and activate 2FA for your Gmail. Here is [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) for 2FA activation.

Comment: Can I get all the devices list logged in, not just recent ones?